# office 365 email limits

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365, office365

I have a small-business client that uses Office 365 as their email provider.

This works fine for everyday email use by employees, but their ERP system, which is configured to use a single email account, generates  a lot of emails, sending out invoices, inventory stock alerts, order status updates, etc, etc.

With an active B2B customer base (over 10,000 customers) with thousands of emails per day generated that are essential to the client relationships, not unwanted SPAM, we are beginning to hit some of the Office 365 email limits.

The maximum of 30 per minute per account is a real issue, especially when sending out the invoices for the day, or when new stock arrives that requires sending individually customized emails to customers that have subscribed to inventory updates for one or more stock items. The limit on number of recipients per day is also an issue given the quantity of customers involved.

My expertise is in customizing and fine tuning the ERP system, I am not an expert on Email systems, which are actually maintained by their hardware and network vendor, however they are looking to me for advice on how to avoid these email issues with the ERP system.

Is there some way to raise the Office 365 limits (my research says no, as they are there to combat SPAM) or a better service to use for the volume of email coming from the ERP system? The client is happy with Office 365 for all other email tasks.

Comment: Use a third party service like SendGrid or the like for the ERP email.

Answer (score 1):

If your customer use Office 365 for their emails, nothing block you to use a small mail server in-house for your ERP system to send those mass emails.

Just be sure to add that IP to your SPF's record, and if your in-house router allow it add a outbound rule that only your in-house server can send anywhere on destination port 25.

Comment: i agree to your answer i would do the same way